# Magento 2 Bundle Product Cache

Tags: magento, caching, magento2

I'm working on a site developed by a third party, which is Magento 2.1 and uses bundle products heavily.  Most of the bundles are made of 260 child products as a choice, and inevitably makes loading the product page for them incredibly slow.

On Mage 1 it was simple enough to use Full Page Caching to cache the bundle product options and speed up the load with pre-caching, but FPC in Mage 2 is clearly very different.

The main slowdown appears to be from the form and options blocks called in the catalog_product_view.xml for the theme, as they iterate over all the child products before rendering the page, so I've tried adding;

```
cacheable="true"
```

To those specific blocks, but it's made no difference.

Anyone have any other idea's for how to cache Magento 2 bundle product pages?

EDIT EDIT

I've just tried plugging the database into a fresh install of Magento 2.1 and can see that bundle products are being added to the var/page_cache directory.  On the client server, the only thing being written to that directory are tags and header info.

So then new angle... why would Magento 2 not write any FPC html to the page_cache directory?  Something higher up the tree has erroneously has cacheable=false set against it perhaps?  I'll get digging

Comment: a way : http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14356/24845 ?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - that is for Magento 1 though, which usefully demonstrates that in Mage1 bundles are cached by default but are not cached in Mage2

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I cannot comment your last post.

Do you try to use Varnish as the HTTP cache ? Magento recommendation is to use Varnish and Redis as cache backend.

Comment: Hi, we're not using Varnish at the moment as we're debugging.  Even using the standard file system, the FPC should create a flat version of the page (save for hole punched/dynamic areas), but the page takes the same amount of time to render on each load - it's still iterating over all the bundle options on each load.

Comment: You can create an internal ticket to Magento 2 support. But just try to set up varnish on your local environment, it is only 1 hour max to set it and I think if will resolve your problem since only Varnish will handle your page after the first attempt.

Comment: Do you try to add $this->_isScopePrivate = false; into your block ? Do you think that you set the cacheable="true" for the right block ?

Comment: thanks for your comments. I'm pretty sure (might be wrong) that putting isScopePrivate in to the block phtml itself is too far down the chain, but will  try and submit a report to mage. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue, and it was a mistake made by the people who built the site, and the module creators of magepal magento2-googletagmanager.  In both instances, the blocks had;

```
cacheable="false"
```

in the layout XML.  Setting this on any block on a page will stop the whole page from cacheing.  So remove that line, and add;

```
$this->_isScopePrivate = true;
```

In to the blocks __construct function.  Problem solved.

Comment: We don't recommend `cacheable=false` or `_isScopePrivate`. We got started on the topic of caching [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-priv.html#config-cache-priv-how-block). It's still incomplete but I hope it helps